# Dimension of product of affine varieties is the sum of dimensions of each variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

How do I prove that the dimension of the product of affine varieties is the sum of dimensions of each affine variety?

I am aware that similar questions had been asked in [Dimension of product of affine varieties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784789/dimension-of-product-of-affine-varieties) and [Dimension of a tensor product of affine rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191667/dimension-of-a-tensor-product-of-affine-rings). In those answers, they seemed to suggest that we consider, by normalization, transcendental bases ${x_1,...,x_n}$ and ${y_1,...,y_m}$ of $A(X)$ and $A(Y)$, then claim ${x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m}$ is a transcendental basis. I think it is clear that ${x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m}$ is algebraic independent, however I am not sure why they form a basis.

A complete proof would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A(X)$ is finitely generated and integral over $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, it is finite over this ring, and we may pick some finite collection of generators of this ring extension $a_1,\cdots,a_r$, each of which is algebraic over $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. Then $K(X)=k(x_1,\cdots,x_n,a_1,\cdots,a_r)$. We make a similar construction for $Y$, where $b_1,\cdots,b_s$ are the generators for $A(Y)$ over $k[y_1,\cdots,y_m]$, and note that $K(Y)=k(y_1,\cdots,y_m,b_1,\cdots,b_s)$. Since $A(X\times Y)\cong A(X)\otimes A(Y)$, the elements $x_i,y_j,a_k,b_l$ generate $A(X\times Y)$ and we see that $$K(X\times Y)=k(x_1,\cdots,x_n,y_1,\cdots,y_m,a_1,\cdots,a_r,b_1,\cdots,b_s)$$ which is the same as saying that $$K(X\times Y)=k(x_1,\cdots,x_n,y_1,\cdots,y_m)(a_1,\cdots,a_r,b_1,\cdots,b_s).$$ This extension is algebraic since it is generated by algebraic elements, so the $x_i$ and $y_j$ considered together form a transcendence basis.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I was wondering are you suggesting that field of fraction of tensor product of $A(X)$ and $A(Y)$ is isomorphic to tensor product of field of fraction of $A(X)$ and $A(Y)$?

Comment: No! I am not suggesting this, because it is wrong (check the case of $X=Y=\Bbb A^1$ for instance). I've altered the wording a little bit to explain how I'm using this.

Comment: Thank you again for your explanation! Am I right that you are treating $x_i,y_j,a_k,b_l$ as $x_i \otimes 1, 1\otimes y_j, a_k\otimes 1, 1\otimes b_l$ and they generate $A(X)\otimes A(Y)$ over $k$?

Comment: Yes, that's true.